# Asp.Net Core MVC with Windows Authentication on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application with Windows Authentication. I published it on IIS server in local network of our company. All works fine, all users log in with their rights. But each time when they open a browser they need to enter their credentials. Each time we see a window for entering the user name and password. How to make a logon automatic?

I added this strings to Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
…
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

//custom authorization
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
   options.AddPolicy("Operator", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new CheckADGroupRequirement(Configuration["RolesConfig:Operator"], Configuration["RolesConfig:Manager"])));
   options.AddPolicy("Manager", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new CheckADGroupRequirement(Configuration["RolesConfig:Manager"])));
});

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CheckADGroupHandler>();
//custom authorization

…
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
…
app.UseAuthentication();
…
}
```

In IIS I set to **Enabled** only Windows Authentication

The only solution I found it was set Automatic logon in Internet Options but I think it’s bad practice.

Comment: No, it's not bad practice *if it's enabled only in the Intranet or trusted zone*. Make sure your site is added to those zones

Comment: BTW this is 100% a browser issue. The *browser* has to handle the security conversation between itself, the server and AD and send the server the appropriate tokens. No passwords are exchanged. Your account is *already* authenticate on the client machine. The browser tells the web server who you already are using a secure protocol

Comment: When I set 'Automatic logon only in Intranet zone' browser requires password. It works correctly only when I set 'Automatic logon with current user and password'. I tried in diferent browsers and result was same.

Comment: Is your site in the Intranet Zone? If not, you need to add it

Comment: hmm... try this, go to "Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager\Add a Windows Credential" on your workstation and add your credentials

Comment: Site is on IIS in company domain. Is it Intranet Zone? Same problem I saw when i develeped project and start it on IIS Express.

Comment: As far as I know, IE related setting like Intranet Zone or else could be managed by AD policy. If your company domain use AD policy, you could set all the company's computer inside your domain to add the domain into Intranet Zone. I suggest you could contract your company's IT to know how it work and how to solve it.

Comment: So the problem is not in the app but in the AD security settings?

Comment: This issue is related with the browser settings and this could be modify by the each client. But Windows server group policy management could manage all the browser setting.

Comment: did you attempt what I said to try @kind_wizard?